# How to handle multiple API calls in android MVI architecture (unidirectional dataflow)?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I am following MVI architecture and what to handle multiple api call results, so my code is something like below, I used https://github.com/RohitSurwase/AAC-MVI-Architecture as reference

**Modal.kt**

```
data class HomeViewState(val postListState: PostListState)

sealed class PostListState {
    object Loading : PostListState()
    data class Success(val postList: List<Post>) : PostListState()
    data class Error(val message: String) : PostListState()
}
```

**ViewModal.kt**

```
private fun fetchPostFeed() {
    composite.add(postUseCase.fetchPostList().subscribe(
        { postList ->
            viewState = viewState.copy(postListState = PostListState.Success(postList))
        },
        { error ->
            viewState = viewState.copy(
                postListState = PostListState.Error(
                    message = error.localizedMessage ?: "Something went wrong while fetching postlist!!!"
                )
            )
            Timber.e(error)
        }
    ))
}
```

**Fragment.kt**

```
override fun renderViewState(viewState: HomeViewState) {
    when (viewState.postListState) {
        PostListState.Loading -> loadPosts()
        is PostListState.Success -> showPostListToUI(viewState.postListState.postList)
        is PostListState.Error -> showErrorLayout(viewState.postListState.message)
    }
}
```

So the flow is when ViewModel init the default state is set to **PostListState.Loading**, this state change fragment's **renderViewState()** is called which emmits load event, which is handled by view model in **fetchPostFeed()**, which will update the state again in case of success or error.

### **The problem**

Now I want to make an API call to load comments also, so I tried to change implementation to something like

**Modal.kt**

```
data class HomeViewState(val postListState: PostListState, val commentsState: CommentsState)

sealed class PostListState {
    object Loading : PostListState()
    data class Success(val postList: PagedList<Post>) : PostListState()
    data class Error(val message: String) : PostListState()
}

sealed class CommentsState {
    object Loading : CommentsState()
    data class Success(val commList: List<Comments>) : CommentsState()
    data class Error(val message: String) : CommentsState()
}
```

And in the fragment we will be

**Fragment.kt**

```
override fun renderViewState(viewState: HomeViewState) {
    when (viewState.postListState) {
        PostListState.Loading -> loadPosts()
        is PostListState.Success -> showPostListToUI(viewState.postListState.postList)
        is PostListState.Error -> showErrorLayout(viewState.postListState.message)
    }

    when (viewState.commentsState) {
        CommentsState.Loading -> loadComments()
        is CommentsState.Success -> showCOmments(viewState.commentsState.commList)
        is CommentsState.Error -> showErrorLayout(viewState.commentsState.message)
    }
}
```

Now the thing is suppose post fetch finished earlier and state is updated to **PostListState.Success** and if comment state is still in **CommentsState.Loading** it will re-trigger the loading of comments, which is not desired.
How can I handle multiple api call so that changeing of one API call's state does't re-trigger event in other api call

Answer (score 0):

For this case I would combine both calls with something like this:

```
sealed class PostListState {
    object Loading : PostListState()
    data class Success(val postList: List<Post>, val commList: List<Comments>) : PostListState()
    data class Error(val message: String) : PostListState()
}
```

Here the name "PostList" would represent the list of posts and their comments, you could change it to something that encompass both for you.

In fetchPostFeed you would call both endpoints concurrently for example, or one after the other, wait for both to return their results and post them in the Success response like 'postList' and 'commList' separately.
Another option is to combine them in a new data class using a mapper (i.e. a list of posts and each one with their respective list of comments).

Using RxJava for example, would be something like this:

```
Observable.zip(
            FetchPostList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
            FetchCommentList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
            BiFunction { firstResponse: PostList,
                         secondResponse: CommentList ->
                Pair(firstResponse, secondResponse)
            })
            .flatMap { resultPair ->
                Observable.just(PostListState.Success(resultPair.first, resultPair.second))
            }
            .onErrorReturn(Error)
            .startWith(Loading)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```